# Mule app fails to deploy because it has not yet been deployed?

Tags: mule

I am having an interesting issue with mule-3.4.0 where I drop in a .zip file containing the files I would like mule to extract and deploy/create anchor for but when I check the logs, it complains that it cannot deploy the application because of a ***FileNotFoundException***

The file that it is looking for is a file that **would** exist if it had extracted the archive.

I can't seem to hit the right keywords to search for this problem in google. Does anybody have any ideas or thoughts about why this is happening?

**NOTE**
The application in question is not the problem because if I extract manually and drop the folder in the mule/apps folder it deploys correctly.

Comment: Is there a space in the Mule deployment path? If yes, it could be https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-8417

Comment: Can you add the server log? (mule.log)

Comment: I am reviving this thread from the dead. So the only thing I have to go off right now is that it seems to be related to the compression scheme of the zip file. From the wiki Zip file format page, the compression scheme that Mule is failing to deploy is 0x00 0x08 which is deflated compression. After recompressing the zip with 7z it shows 0x00 0x00 for no compression method and Mule can deploy this one. The deflated compression comes from truezip.java.net library. Changing this library is not a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

That particular version of mule had a nasty bug that would make some deployables not deploy when the filename had some characters '+' or spaces.

Try and remove any characters from the filename that might seem "odd" and retry the deployment. Also consider that in 3.4.0 it was implemented the deletion of deployables when deployment failed.